# Need WURFL to work only for mobiles

Tags: asp.net-mvc

At present i am using the below code for detecting mobiles, tablets. But i need to restrict this code to Mobile. Your suggestions can be appreciated if provided the solution.

```
DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0, new DefaultDisplayMode("Mobile")
        {
            ContextCondition = (context =>
            {
                var manager = (context.Cache[WurflManagerCacheKey] as IWURFLManager);
                var cabablities = manager.GetDeviceForRequest(context.Request.UserAgent);
                return cabablities.GetCapability("is_wireless_device") == "true";
                //return cabablities.GetCapability("mobile_browser").Contains("Opera");
                //return cabablities.UserAgent.Contains("Opera");
            })
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `is_wireless_device` and `is_tablet` capabilities to isolate only mobile phones:

```
if (is_tablet == false && is_wireless_device == true) {
   //Must be a mobile phone
}
```